# Powershell start-job arg has no data after upgrading to v3

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have a script used to deploy upgrades to a piece of vendor software. The script leverages xml to map different deployment paths. I noticed this stopped working this week after a forced upgrade to powershell 3. Below is a small demo script to illustrate the issue:

```
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content (Get-Item (".\FooBar.xml")))
$foobar = $xml.Stuff.FooBars.Foobar 

$ScriptBlock = {        
    $foobar = $args[0]

    write-host "Inside the job..."
    write-host ("Foobar     : "+$foobar)
    write-host ("Foobar.Foo : "+$foobar.Foo)
    write-host ("Args       : "+$args)
}

write-host "Outside the job..."
write-host ("Foobar: "+$foobar)
write-host ("Foobar.Foo : "+$foobar.Foo)

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -Args $foobar | Out-Null        
While (Get-Job -State "Running") { Start-Sleep 2 }               

write-host ("Jobs Completed.")    
Get-Job | Receive-Job          
Remove-Job *
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Stuff xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FooBars>
    <FooBar>
      <Foo>ThisIsAFoo</Foo>
      <Bar>ThisIsABar</Bar>
    </FooBar>
  </FooBars> 
</Stuff>
```

Output on v2:

```
Outside the job...
Foobar: System.Xml.XmlElement
Foobar.Foo : ThisIsAFoo
Jobs Completed.
Inside the job...
Foobar     : System.Collections.ArrayList System.Collections.ArrayList
Foobar.Foo : ThisIsAFoo
Args       : System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Output on v3:

```
Outside the job...
Foobar: System.Xml.XmlElement
Foobar.Foo : ThisIsAFoo
Jobs Completed.
Inside the job...
Foobar     : System.Collections.ArrayList System.Collections.ArrayList
Foobar.Foo : 
Args       : System.Collections.ArrayList
```

So note that in v2 Foobar.Foo can be determined and in v3 it cannot. Any ideas what would cause this and the best work around? Scope issue? In my larger script the XmlElement is passed to additional functions, so I would like to avoid converting that to a different object or breaking it into its properties and sending them individually.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. I haven't found the exact cause yet, but as a workaround, you can add the flag -PSVersion 2.0 to your start-job line.